# Error Landroid/support/v7/widget/SearchView$5 when using Action Bar compat library

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

Ok, ive properly imported the v7-appcompat library(yes i have unchecked the dependencies),on using in a project i get the list of errors in log cat.
    **The application works fine on and android Moto g i.e on android 4.4.2  , but not on my LG p500 2.2.2,**

I also followed the instructions for importing an android resource library from the official website that is http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

I am starting to think that this an android bug , please help

```
- 04-14 19:59:22.223: W/dalvikvm(12718): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 318:          Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getActivityLogo (Landroid/content/ComponentName;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
- 04-14 19:59:22.223: W/dalvikvm(12718): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 314: Landroid/content/pm/ApplicationInfo;.loadLogo  (Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
  04-14 19:59:22.463: W/dalvikvm(12718): Link of class 'Landroid/support/v7/widget/SearchView$5;' failed
  04-14 19:59:22.463: E/dalvikvm(12718): Could not find class 'android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$5', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.addOnLayoutChangeListenerToDropDownAnchorSDK11
  04-14 19:59:22.463: W/dalvikvm(12718): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 840 (Landroid/support/v7/widget/SearchView$5;) in Landroid/support/v7/widget/SearchView;
  04-14 19:59:22.663: W/dalvikvm(12718): VFY: unable to resolve direct method 8207: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;.<init> (Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;)V
```

My code is straight forward ,,, action.xml(the menu for action bar)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      xmlns:lol="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
          android:id="@+id/item1"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_copy"
          android:title="@string/title"
          lol:showAsAction="ifRoom"
          />

    <item
    android:id="@+id/searchActivity"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    lol:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    lol:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>    
    </menu>
```

The android manifest file is as follows

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.gamehaschanged"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gamehaschanged.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The mainActivity also straight foward is as follows

```
package com.example.gamehaschanged;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.searchActivity);
    return true;
}
```

}

The project is not crashing but giving warnings and an error , I dont want any problems later in the project

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18552795/2558604
These guys think its a bug. I too think its a bug. If everything works fine now, I think you wont be facing problems in future.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have 50 reputation to comment so I'll answer it here.

You will need both libraries:

```
android-support-v4.jar
android-support-v7-appcompat.jar
```

if you're planning to use the `appcompat` library in your Android project.

You can either embed the above JAR files in your project by copying them from `\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\libs` directory to your project's `libs` directory.

Or, you can share the appcompat library across different Android projects by doing:

1. In Eclipse, select **File | Import | Existing Projects into workspace**. Then, click **Next**.
2. Click **Browse**, and browse to the directory of Android appcompat directory. The default directory should be: ..\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat.
3. Click **Finish** to add the new project.
4. Select the **Properties tab of an Android project**.
5. In the Properties screen, select the **Android** option (on the left pane), then click **Add**, and select the appcompat library from the list.
6. Click **OK** to save the changes.

Comment: Now you got enough reputation... And your answer is correct, I think. ;)

Comment: well except for the Android dependencies of the project everything has both v4 and v7 appcompat ,,,,how to add v4 here ??

Comment: now im getting R. error , R cannot be resolved to a variable, when i tried the first method

Comment: Check your import statements. Make sure `import android.R;` does not get imported anywhere in your project. Also, check your xml files to see if you have any errors.

Comment: i have imported the classes just like you have said, earlier i followed instructions from the android.developers website. I am pretty sure that I have imported the dependencies in the right way, there must be something else to this

Comment: Delete all the appcompat stuff you have done so far and follow my instructions above and it will work. I don't know what's on Android Developers website so I can't comment.

Comment: Ok i tried copying the libs, I got the R. error because its unable to work with the custom tag ------------------  xmlns:actionBartry="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"  like its unable to find "actionViewClass" the error given is --------------------: No resource identifier found for attribute 'actionViewClass' in package 'com.example.lasttry'

Comment: Okay, instead of embedding, try the other method I posted above - do the six steps and you should be able to share the appcompat library for all your Android projects. Note: This will resolve all the conflict errors you have. But to use the ActionBar, you'll need some codes to enable it.

Comment: Hey I updated my question beacuase the project seems to work fine on an android MOTO G any suggestions if this could be android bug??